# “BloomRPC” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Tags: macos, grpc, macos-catalina

After downloading BloomRPC from the github [repo](https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc) and running `brew cask install bloomrpc`, when I try to open the BloomRPC application I get "BloomRPC cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified." I've tried going to Security and Privacy -> Developer Tools -> and enabling BloomRPC under "Allow the apps below to run software locally that does not meet the system's security policy", but I still get the same error message.

I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.5. How do I open the BloomRPC application?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try to build BloomRPC from source (as they mentioned in their repo) Or you can simply bypass this error go navigate to SystemPreference -> Security&Privacy.
Under General tab, you will see a statement about BloomRPC, click on Open Anyway to suppress the warning and continue to use.

Answer (score 9):

Follow these steps:

1. Type the following command in terminal - sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine
2. Add space at the end of command
3. Drag and drop the app into the terminal window right after the command and hit 'return' key
4. Enter password and you are good to go.

For Bloomrpc the command will look like this:

sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Applications/BloomRPC.app

Comment: This works on local machine. How to make it work for all users if we share the app to them? How can we make it verify for all users if they download the app from website? Thanks